# How to conform to a protocol with a generic superscript affordance in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics

TL;DR
How can I conform to the `supscript` function of a protocol in my implementation?

Protocol:

```swift
protocol DataStore {
    //...
    subscript<T>(id: T.ID) -> T where T: Identifiable { get set }
}
```

Neither

```swift
subscript<T>(id: T.ID) -> T where T : Identifiable {
        get { Project() }//just to return anything for the time being…
        set {}
    }
```

nor

```swift
subscript(id: Task.ID) -> Task {
        get { Project() }//just to return anything for the time being…
        set {}
    }
```

work...

The details:

I have developed a habit of creating specific data stores for my models. They all have the same functionality. A specific example could look like this:

```swift
final class ProjectDataStore: ObservableObject {
    {
        static let shared = ProjectDataStore()
        
        let persistence = AtPersistLocally.shared // that's from a personal package I made that handles saving and loading locally as json files
        
        @Published var projects: [Project] {
            didSet { //save }
        }
        
        private init(projects: [Project]? = nil) {
            //load from persistence
        }
        
        subscript(id: Project.ID) -> Project? {
            get { //return project with id }
            set { //set project at id }
        }
        
        func getBinding(by id: Project.ID) -> Binding<Project> {
            //return Binding
        }
        
        func getProjectBy(taskId: Task.ID) -> Project {
            //return instance
        }
        
        private func getIndex(by id: Project.ID) -> Int? {
            //return  index in array
        }
        
        private func load() -> [Project] {
            //load from persistence
        }
        
        private func save() {
            //save from persistence
        }
}
```

While this works as expected, I'd like to be able to introduce a protocol that I could when adding new functionality / models to have a blueprint on what's necessary for my `DataStore`.

Here is my first attempt:

```swift
protocol DataStore {
    static var shared: Self { get }
}

extension DataStore {
    var persistence: AtPersistLocally {
        get {
            AtPersistLocally.shared
        }
    }
}
```

To also conform to `ObservableObject`, I introduce a `typealias`

```swift
typealias ObservableObjectDataStore = DataStore & ObservableObject
```

and change my model to conform to this new `typealias`:

```swift
final class ProjectDataStore: ObservableObjectDataStore {
//...
}
```

With this, I already have a static instance and access to persistence available.
Next step of course is to move more and more properties to the protocol–which is what I am struggling with right now.

Let's look at `superscript` first of all: I guess I understand what needs to be added to the protocol:

```swift
protocol DataStore {
    //...
    subscript<T>(id: T.ID) -> T where T: Identifiable { get set }
}
```

My problem now is that I don't know how to go about conforming to this `subscript` now while also getting access to a concrete model from the generic `T` from the implementation. This attempt…

```swift
final class ProjectDataStore: ObservableObjectDataStore {
    //...
    subscript<T>(id: T.ID) -> T where T : Identifiable {
        get { Project() }//just to return anything for the time being…
        set {}
    }
}
```

…leads to the error message `Cannot convert return expression of type 'Task' to return type 'T'`.

If I go with…

```swift
final class ProjectDataStore: ObservableObjectDataStore {
    //...
    subscript(id: Task.ID) -> Task {
        get { Project() }//just to return anything for the time being…
        set {}
    }
}
```

…the error message changes to `Type 'TaskDataStore' does not conform to protocol 'DataStore'`.

So I guess basically what I am asking is: how can I conform to my protocol's generic `superscript` in my implementation of `ProjectDataStore`?

I have a feeling that I am not too far of, but a critical info is obviously missing…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
subscript<T>(id: T.ID) -> T where T: Identifiable { get set }
```

This says that the caller may pick any Identifiable `T`, and this method promise return a value of that type. This can't be implemented (other than calling `fatalError()` and crashing). Identifiable doesn't even promise that the type has an `init`. Your protocol is impossible.

What you probably meant to write is, which says that a given DataStore will return some specific Identifiable type (not "whatever type the caller requests"):

```
protocol DataStore {
    associatedType Item: Identifiable
    subscript(id: Item.ID) -> Item { get set }
}
```

But I expect this would be much better implemented without a protocol, and just use a generic struct:

```
struct DataStore<Item: Identifiable> { ... }
```

Comment: I can confirm that this is working for me, the `associatedType` is what I missed so far.